# Compare iteration values using handlebars

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I want to compare iteration values using handlebars. This is my code

```
{{#each accounts}}
   {{#each projects}}
      {{#if}} (compare accounts.project_id with projects._id)
          // display the project name
      {{else}}
          // display not found
      {{/if}}
   {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Please help. I'm new to handlebars/

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`{{compare}}`](https://github.com/helpers/handlebars-helpers#comparison) helper from the [`handlebars-helpers`](https://github.com/helpers/handlebars-helpers) module.

```
{{#each accounts}}
   {{#each projects}}
      {{#compare accounts.project_id "==" projects._id)
          // display the project name
      {{else}}
          // display not found
      {{/compare}}
   {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Refer to the [documentation](https://github.com/helpers/handlebars-helpers#install) on how to install and use the helpers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so with a simple [helpers](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html) in `Handlebars` like so:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('if_eq', function(a, b, opts) {
    if(a == b)
        return opts.fn(this);
    else
        return opts.inverse(this);
});
```

and in your code...

```
 {{#each accounts}}
     {{#each projects}}
       {{#if_eq accounts.project_id projects._id}}
          // display the project name
      {{else}}
          // display not found
      {{/if_eq}}
   {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```